# Слияние подстрок в PHP

Tags: php

Имеется массив с ключами идущими по порядку. Мне необходимо создать новый массив в каждой строке которого будет по несколько значений предыдущего массива. Как это сделать?

Вот пример. Имеется:

```
('1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3','4'=>'4','5'=>'5','6'=>'6')
```

Надо чтобы получилось :

```
('1'=>'1,2''2'=>'3,4''3'=>'5,6');
```

Comment: Странная задача какая-то. Еще более странно, что нумерация ключей не с нуля. Если бы была с нуля - можно было бы очень просто и легко сделать: `$result = array_map(function($item) {return implode(',',$item);},array_chunk($array,3));` вместо `3` можно подставить любое число - ни один элемент не будет потерян.

Comment: Нумерация с нуля) я немного затупил при оформлении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно существенно упростить:

```
$int = 4; // Кол-во значений в одном элементе массива
$arr = ['1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3','4'=>'4','5'=>'5','6'=>'6'];

$all = count($arr);
$int <= $all ?: $int = $all;

$join = function() use(&$out, &$i, &$tmp) {
    $out[++$i] = join(',', $tmp);
    $tmp = [];
};

$out = [];
$i = 0;

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $tmp[] = $v;
    $k % $int ?: $join();
}

empty($tmp) ?: $join();

echo '<pre>', print_r($out, 1), '</pre>';
```

> Результат:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1,2,3,4
    [2] => 5,6
)
```

**UPD:** Но так как выяснилось, что нумерация ключей результирующего массива идёт с нуля, то много проще будет вариант со встроенными инструментами для работы с массивами:

```
$int = 4; // Кол-во значений в одном элементе массива
$arr = ['1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3','4'=>'4','5'=>'5','6'=>'6'];

$result = array_map(function($item) {
    return implode(',', $item);
}, array_chunk($arr, $int));

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

> Результат такой же:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1,2,3,4
    [2] => 5,6
)
```

Comment: `в каждой строке которого будет по несколько значений` не 2 ;)

Comment: @Visman а, точно )) Спешка на работе... До вечера исправлю, спс :)

Comment: @Visman подправил свой ответ )

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str="";
$numberOfElements= ; //Кол-во элементов в одной строке после слияния.
end($str);
$lastKey = key($str);
$startid=0;
$numberOfStrings=ceil($lastKey/$numberOfElements);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfStrings; $i++) {

    for ($id = $startid; $id < $startid+$numberOfElements; $id++) {
        $subString[$i][$id] = $str[$id];

    }
    $startid+=$numberOfElements;
    $array[$i]=$subString[$i];
    $comma_separated[$i] = implode(" ", $array[$i]);

}




print_r($comma_separated);
```

Как-то так у меня получилось. Наверняка можно и оптимальнее :)